# C++ using method of inherited template member

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to have a class with a template member. The template member must be an inherited class. I have error when I call the class methods. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base
{
public:
    Base (std::string param) {text=param;}
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual void print(){std::cout<<text<<std::endl;};

    std::string text;
    };
class Child1 : public Base
{
public:
    Child1(const std::string& param):Base(param){ }
    ~Child1() {}

};
class Child2 : public Base
{
public:
    Child2(const std::string& param):Base(param){ }
    ~Child2() {}

};

template <typename T>
class Adapter
{
public:
    Adapter(){};
    const T* get() const {return value;}
    void setValue(T* rhs) {value=rhs;}    
    void print(){value->print();}
    void test(){std::cout<<"Adapter method"<<std::endl;}
private:
    T* value;

    };

int main() {



  Child1 ex1("name1");
  Child2 ex2("name2");

  Adapter<Base *> adapt;
  Adapter<Child1 *> adapt1;
  Adapter<Child2 *> adapt2;
  
  std::cout << typeid(adapt2).name() << std::endl;
  adapt2.test();
  adapt1.setValue(&ex1);
  adapt1.print();
}
```

I have these error:

```
 In function 'int main()':
67:23: error: no matching function for call to 'Adapter<Child1*>::setValue(Child1*)'
67:23: note: candidate is:

47:11: note: void Adapter<T>::setValue(T*) [with T = Child1*]
47:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Child1*' to 'Child1**'
 In instantiation of 'void Adapter<T>::print() [with T = Child1*]':
68:16:   required from here

48:18: error: request for member 'print' in '*((Adapter<Child1*>*)this)->Adapter<Child1*>::value', which is of pointer type 'Child1*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

Could you help me to find my errors?

Comment: `Adapter<Base *> adapt();` declares a *function*, that takes no arguments and returns a `Adapter<Base *>` object by value. Drop the parentheses so you have `Adapter<Base *> adapt;` instead.

Comment: Thanks you. I edited my code and my question

Comment: `int f()` is the prototype of a no parameter function that returns an int. `int f`, defines an int. Same for any type... Read [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 1):

> Could you help me to find my errors?

The **first error**:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Child1*’ to ‘Child1**
```

is because `&ex1` is of type `Child1*` but `adapt1` is of type `Adapter<Child1*>` meaning that the corresponding member function `setValue` takes a parameter of type `T* = Child**`. Essentially, you're passing a `Child*` to `setValue` while it expects a `Child**`. That is, the type of the actual argument you are passing does not matches with the parameter type of the member function.

---

The **second error**:

```
error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘*((Adapter*)this)->Adapter::value’, which is of pointer type ‘Child1*’
```

is because the data member `value` is of type `T* = Child**` and thus when you wrote:

```
value->print(); //this is equivalen to (*value).print();
```

you're trying to call a member function named `print` on `*value` which is of type `Child1*`. But `Child1*` is a pointer type and has no member functions. Thus you get the second mentioned error.